# ngspice keeps reporting an unknown parameter

Tags: transistors, simulation, spice, kicad, ngspice

I built a circuit in KiCad to simulate the behavior of the [Maxim MAX3665](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/comms/optical-communications/MAX3665.html). Here is the circuit:

```
.title KiCad schematic
.include "/home/user/Documents/School/2020-Summer/Tacca/SPICE/3665Circuit.lib"
XU1 VCC VIN NC_01 Net-_C1-Pad1_ GND NC_02 NC_03 GND MAX3665
V1 VCC GND 3.3
V2 VIN GND pulse(V1=0, V2=3.3, TD=500p, TR=1p, TF=1p, PW=500p, PER=1n)
C1 Net-_C1-Pad1_ GND 1000p
.save @v1[i]
.save @v2[i]
.save @c1[i]
.save V(Net-_C1-Pad1_)
.save V(Net-_U1-Pad3_)
.save V(OUTN)
.save V(OUTP)
.save V(VCC)
.save V(VIN)
.tran 1p 2n
.end
```

Here is the `.lib` file for the MAX3665. I tweaked the file provided by Maxim since it had some control lines. The original model can be seen in the appendix of [this pdf](https://www.maximintegrated.com/content/dam/files/design/tools/modeling-simulation/spice/fiber/app_3665eua.pdf).

```
* 3665 Output Model
************************************************
* XOUTPKG 2001 2002 50 51 OUTPKG
* XOUTDRV 50 51 101 OUTDRV
************************************************
* .SUBCKT MAX3665 VCC IN NC FILT GND OUTP OUTN GND
.SUBCKT MAX3665 6001 6002 6003 6004 6005 6006 6007 6005
* XOUTPKG OUTP OUTN INTP INTN OUTPKG
XOUTPKG 6006 6007 7001 7002 OUTPKG
* XOUTDRV INTP INTN VCC IN GND FILT OUTDRV
XOUTDRV 7001 7002 6001 6002 6005 6004 OUTDRV
.ENDS
************************************************
* .SUBCKT OUTDRV INTP INTN VCC IN GND FILT
.SUBCKT OUTDRV 50 51 101 1 0 3
R1 2 1 50
R2 4 0 50
C1 2 0 12.5p
C2 4 0 12.5p
RFILT 101 3 1.5k
* Differential Pair
XQ1 50 2 5 0 H14E04_2
XQ2 51 4 5 0 H14E04_2
* Biasing Current
I1 5 0 5.335m
R3 101 50 50
R4 101 51 50
* Offset Capacitors
C3 50 51 1.2p
C4 50 0 10p
C5 51 0 10p
* ESD Structures
XD1 50 101 0 HDE381011
XD2 0 50 0 HDE381011
XD3 101 51 0 HDE381011
XD4 0 51 0 HDE381011
* PAD structures
XP1 50 0 pad3
XP2 51 0 pad3
.ENDS OUTDRV
************************************************
************************************************
* .SUBCKT OUTPKG OUTP OUTN INTP INTN
.SUBCKT OUTPKG 2001 2002 50 51
* Calculated package parameters
RP1 50 60 .0399
RP2 51 61 .0399
LP1 60 2001 1.446n
LP2 61 2002 1.455n
CP1 2001 0 .254p
CP2 2002 0 .193p
CP12 2001 2002 .061p
.ENDS OUTPKG
************************************************
************************************************
* Q1 and Q2 transistor models
.SUBCKT H14E04_2 1 2 3 21
CP1EPI 1 2 24.369F
CP1P2 12 3 39.268F
CTRENCH 1 20 30.614F
RBX 2 12 10.277 TC=2.663M
RCX 1 10 11.754 TC=2.354M,979.573N
RCI 10 11 618.650M TC=2.354M,979.573N
REX 13 3 1.397 TC=123.150U
RSUB 20 21 3.098K
QP 20 10 12 20 TXP 2 OFF
QN 11 12 13 11 TX 2
.MODEL TX NPN( IS=3.326E-017 XTI=3 EG=1.140 BF=232.533 BR=20 XTB=450M
+ VAF=29 VAR=3.500 NF=1.010 NR=1.020 NE=1.650 NC=1.560 IKF=126.546M
+ IKR=2.318M ISE=1.573E-020 ISC=2.022E-029 RB=20.554 RBM=15.416
+ IRB=20.223M CJE=107.672F MJE=490M VJE=940M FC=990M CJC=21.929F
+ MJC=470M VJC=850M TF=3.778P TR=19N XTF=1 VTF=1K ITF=59.621M PTF=5
+ KF=1.500F AF=1 )
.MODEL TXP PNP( IS=1.968E-018 CJE=21.929F MJE=470M VJE=850M
CJC=21.582F
+ MJC=400M VJC=650M BF=10K BR=809.067U TF=1N FC=900M )
.ENDS H14E04_2
************************************************
************************************************
* ESD Diode Models
.SUBCKT HDE381011 1 2 21
CP1EPI 1 4 79.338F
QD 5 4 1 5 QESD
RS 4 2 2.385 TC=3.113M,2.489U
RSUB 5 21 2.318K
CTRENCH 2 5 40.181F
.MODEL QESD PNP( IS=9.707E-018 NF=1.050 BF=800M BR=600U CJE=127.405F
+ VJE=600M MJE=400M CJC=64.825F VJC=650M MJC=400M )
.ENDS HDE381011
************************************************
************************************************
* PAD Models
.SUBCKT PAD3 1 3
CPAD 1 10 87.228F
REPI 10 20 250.111M TC=4.800M,5U
CTRENCH 21 20 22.394F
DS 21 20 DSUB
RS 3 21 369.115
.MODEL DSUB D( IS=12.656F CJO=885.938F M=500M VJ=450M )
.ENDS PAD3
************************************************
.END
```

Here is the error message I received when I tried to simulate it:

```
Circuit: KiCad schematic 

Error on line 0 :
  c.xu1.xoutdrv.xq1.cjc=21.582f xu1.xoutdrv.xq1.mjc=400m xu1.xoutdrv.xq1.vjc=650m bf=10k br=809.067u tf=1n fc=900m )
 unknown parameter (xu1.xoutdrv.xq1.vjc) 
Error on line 0 :
  c.xu1.xoutdrv.xq2.cjc=21.582f xu1.xoutdrv.xq2.mjc=400m xu1.xoutdrv.xq2.vjc=650m bf=10k br=809.067u tf=1n fc=900m )
 unknown parameter (xu1.xoutdrv.xq2.vjc) 
Error on line 5 :
  v2 vin 0 pulse(v1=0, v2=3.3, td=500p, tr=1p, tf=1p, pw=500p, per=1n)
no such parameter on this device
```

Out of curiosity, I deleted the unknown parameter (knowing full well that it was necessary for proper simulation), and it simply claimed the next parameter was unknown. Rinse and repeat with deleting parameters until:

```
Circuit: KiCad schematic 

Error on line 0 :
  c.xu1.xoutdrv.xq1.cjc=21.582f xu1.xoutdrv.xq1.mjc=400m null 
 unknown parameter (null) 
Error on line 0 :
  c.xu1.xoutdrv.xq2.cjc=21.582f xu1.xoutdrv.xq2.mjc=400m null 
 unknown parameter (null) 
Error on line 5 :
  v2 vin 0 pulse(v1=0, v2=3.3, td=500p, tr=1p, tf=1p, pw=500p, per=1n)
no such parameter on this device
```

Googling around suggested this could be a SPICE version error, but I have xspice enabled so I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in the subcircuit of `H14E04_2`, the `.model` for the `TXP` has a new line that does not use the concatenation `+`. Try modifying it to:

`+ CJC=21.582F`

Comment: ...or simply integrate it in the line above (backspace at the beginning of the line). Be sure to leave a space between it and `VJE=850M` above.